# Copy link address for anchor tag with ng-click and href="javascript:void(0)"

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-click

Sample Html

```
   <a href="javascript:void(0)" ng-click="someFunction()" />
```

Controller will have the following function

```
someFunction() {
  window.open('http://www.example.com');
}
```

When we click the anchor tag, things works as expected, and it opens a new tab in the browser with `example.com`

Is there a possible way to get the url, when we **right click on the anchor tag and select "Copy link address"**, which can be used to paste in file/email/another browser.

Currently "Copy link address" provides void:(0)

Answer (score 0):

"Copy link address" option provides href of anchors

To accomplish your goal you can modify your function as

```
$scope.someFunction = function() {
  var $temp = $("<input>");
  $("body").append($temp);
  $temp.val('http://www.example.com').select();
  document.execCommand("copy");
  $temp.remove()
  window.open('http://www.example.com');
}
```

In this way, your link will be copied with a click!